# animate.css : Animate on hover script

Tags: javascript, hover, jquery-animate, animate.css

I'm trying to accomplish a hover animation using JS, but my skills with said language are very limited. I have this script in my script.js file, as it is the only script I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    animationHover('#intro-logo' 'tada')

function animationHover(element, animation){
    element = $(element);
    element.hover(
        function() {
            element.addClass('animated ' + animation);          
        },
        function(){
            //wait for animation to finish before removing classes
            window.setTimeout( function(){
                element.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
            }, 2000);           
        });
}

}

})();
```

The goal is that when I hover over #intro-logo, the script will add classes .animated and .tada which will animate the darn thing! However I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string which brings me to

```
animationHover('#intro-logo' 'tada')
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I used a tutorial [here](http://www.josebrowne.com/tutorial-easy-css-animations-with-animate.css.html#.UgUKmJK1H2E) and it worked for the guy, but I'm having no such luck. I would sincerely appreciate anyone's help.

Thank you in advance, this community is amazing. This is my first question, but all of you guys have helped me solve hundreds of problems along my rocky way to web development prowess (much of which obviously still remains ahead).

Edit: I added the missing comma and now it seems there is a problem with the way I'm ending the document. Posted is my entire JS file, how to I properly close everything? })(); doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you need a comma: `animationHover('#intro-logo', 'tada')`

Comment: You need to close the `ready` with `});`

Comment: You have an extra `}` at the end. and you don't need to invoke the return value from the `ready` function.

Comment: It's that easy, you have to close as many brackets as you've opened.

Answer (score 0):

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/daTdP/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    animationHover('#intro-logo', 'tada')

    function animationHover(element, animation) {
        element = $(element);
        element.hover(

        function () {
            element.addClass('animated ' + animation);
        },

        function () {
            //wait for animation to finish before removing classes
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                element.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
            }, 2000);
        });
    }

});
```

Removed unnecessary `}` and `()` at the end, as well as added the comma.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not necessarily need JS you could use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#intro-logo").hover(function () {
             $(this).toggleClass('animated tada');
     });
   });
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AYDrJ/4/)

alternatively you could also do it in pure CSS with the :hover pseudo class